# Changing the format of textbox date to another textbox on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want a user to see a detailed date when he selects a day from the jQuery Datepicker. However the format I want to post and save in the database has to be different that the one showed.

As you see, the 2 textboxes have this `DD, d MM yy` format. This is what I want to show to the people so it stays that way. But for my code to work correctly, this date must be saved in the database in the format of `Y-m-d` (like 2012-03-23)

I want to avoid using PHP code after the form submits for the transformation. Maybe with a hidden field that automatically gets and transforms the value of `#enarksi` and `#liksi` ? After that I will post the hidden's fields value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var m = date.getMonth(),
        d = date.getDate(),
        y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#enarksi, #liksi').datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(y, m, d),
        dateFormat: 'DD, d MM yy'
    });

    $("#enarksi, #liksi").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["el"]);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the onSelect event of the datepicker, you can parse the date when it changes and set it to a hidden field.

```
$('#enarksi, #liksi').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(y, m, d),
    dateFormat: 'DD, d MM yy',
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        // Parse the selected date
        var instance = $(this).data('datepicker'),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                selectedDate, instance.settings);

        // Reformat
        var formatted = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);

        // Set the formatted date
        $('#hiddenField').val(formatted);         
    }
});
```

You just need to find some way to select a hidden field. For example, you could use a `data-` attribute on your textboxes, such as `data-hidden-field`, and then just replace the last line of code with `$('#' + $(this).data('hidden-field')).val(formatted);`

Comment: I added it into my existing code as you posted it but I can't get it working. The datepicker is not working now

Comment: I've modified my code to include it into your call to datepicker. Can you try it?

Comment: There was also a bug in my code that I've fixed. You can see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/jTG79/1/

Comment: One more thing though. I spit the script in two, one for each textboxes. On the second textbox (liksi) I want the min date to be the one that is selected in "enarksi". Please see it here http://jsfiddle.net/4SEvy/1/

Comment: You can use `$('#liksi').datepicker('option','minDate',date);`. See http://jsfiddle.net/4SEvy/3/